# List of all tables across all databases with row count of each table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the list of ALL tables across ALL databases in a server along with row count of EACH table.

For now, I have developed a code that gives the list of all tables with all databases. However, I need help in adding row count of each of these tables.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[List_of_tables_in_All_Databases]
    (@clean BIT = 1, 
     @debugEnabled BIT = 0)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @message  NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @procName NVARCHAR(250) = object_name(@@procid);

    DECLARE @processingProcStart DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @processingprocTime  INT = 0

    SET @message = 'List_of_tables_in_All_Databases START: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121);

    EXEC [dbo].[usp_KREOInsertLog] @type = 'INFO', @source = 'Analysis', @storedProcedure = @procName, @debugLevel = 1, @message = @message, @show = @debugEnabled

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#AllTables ') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #AllTables 

SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #AllTables 
(
    ServerName NVARCHAR(200),
    DBName NVARCHAR(200),
    SchemaName NVARCHAR(200),
    TableName NVARCHAR(200),
    [RowCount] INT 
)

DECLARE @SearchSvr NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchDB NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchS NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchTbl NVARCHAR(200),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SearchSvr = NULL  --Search for Servers, NULL for all Servers
SET @SearchDB = NULL   --Search for DB, NULL for all Databases
SET @SearchS = 'dbo'   --Search for Schemas, NULL for all Schemas
SET @SearchTbl = NULL  --Search for Tables, NULL for all Tables

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME
        ,''?''
        ,s.name
        ,t.name
        FROM sys.tables t 
         JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
         WHERE @@SERVERNAME LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchSvr, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchDB, '') + '%''
         AND s.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchS, '') + '%''
         AND t.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchTbl, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''SSISDB'')
           '
-- Remove the '--' from the last statement in the WHERE clause to exclude system tables

INSERT INTO #AllTables (ServerName, DBName, SchemaName, TableName)
    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL

SELECT * FROM #AllTables
```

Can someone help with writing the code that gives the row counts for these tables?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [mysql]? Note: *MySQL* doesn't stand for "**My**crosoft **SQL**".

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'll note that you can probably get better performance out of this by replacing this: `AND s.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchS, '') + '%''` with something like : `AND (@SearchS IS NULL OR s.name LIKE ''%' @SearchS + '%'')`. That will allow you to get some short-circuit logic when these parameters are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a quick way to get row counts using SQL Server metadata. You could add this into your query in `@SQL`:

```
SELECT [Rows] = SUM(row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=@YourObjectId   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

I believe that would make the full `@SQL` as follows. Untested, but should at least be pretty close:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME
        ,''?''
        ,s.name
        ,t.name
        ,SUM(p.row_count) as [rows]
        FROM sys.tables t 
         JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id=s.schema_id 
         LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
           ON p.object_id = t.object_id
             and (p.index_id = 0 or p.index_id = 1)
         WHERE @@SERVERNAME LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchSvr, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchDB, '') + '%''
         AND s.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchS, '') + '%''
         AND t.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchTbl, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''SSISDB'')
        GROUP BY s.name, t.name
           '
```

Comment: @Nafisa, there are a couple of options for leveraging system tables, and the one Jeff outlines is the most efficient (and the one he typed faster then me +1). The pros and cons of each are nicely laid out in this [Brent Ozar blog post.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also show the size in MB along with that info, I always use this query for that

```
select t.NAME AS TableName,
       i.name as indexName,
       sum(p.rows) / count(a.total_pages) as RowCounts,
       count(a.total_pages) as page_count,
       sum(a.total_pages) as TotalPages, 
       sum(a.used_pages) as UsedPages, 
       sum(a.data_pages) as DataPages,
       (sum(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 as TotalSpaceMB, 
       (sum(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 as UsedSpaceMB, 
       (sum(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 as DataSpaceMB 
from   sys.tables t
  inner join sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
  inner join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
  inner join sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
where  t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
and    i.OBJECT_ID > 255   
and    i.index_id <= 1
group by t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name
order by sum(p.rows) / count(a.total_pages) DESC
```

Comment: You'd better add `and    a.[type] = 2` to the where clause or you could be unpleasantly surprised sometime.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin care to explain why ?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I could understand `and a.[type] > 0` but why would you only want LOB data rows ?

Comment: Because sys.allocation_units.container_id = sys.partitions.partition_id only for [type] = 2 [sys.allocation_units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Not sure if we are talking about the same thing here. If I add `and a.[type] = 2` to my where clause, then in my database I only get those tables that have LOB data in stead of all tables.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin This is also what I found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I just read the part about the `container_id` in the documentation and it suggest what you are writing, however if I check the data returned by my query I find it to be accurat. So might there be a problem with this documentation or did we overlooked something here?

Comment: Take a table with LOB data. If you try to get `sum(p.rows)` using your query, you must get double count. I was not correct about adding `and a.[type] = 2` to the where clause - it's my bad, but `sum(p.rows)` from the query could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Complete example combining the work done by [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57220758/119624) and the original question. I also fixed an issue where database names have '.'s in them, generated the pivot columns:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ServerTablesPivot') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE #ServerTablesPivot
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE #ServerTablesPivot
    (
        DBName NVARCHAR(200),
        SchemaName NVARCHAR(200),
        TableName NVARCHAR(200),
        [RowCount] INT 
    )

DECLARE @SearchSvr NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchDB NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchS NVARCHAR(200),
        @SearchTbl NVARCHAR(200),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @SearchDB = 'UAT.Tenant00'   --Search for DB, NULL for all Databases
SET @SearchS = 'dbo'   --Search for Schemas, NULL for all Schemas
SET @SearchTbl = NULL  --Search for Tables, NULL for all Tables

SELECT @SQL = 'USE [?]; SELECT
        ''?''
        ,s.name
        ,t.name
        ,SUM(p.rows) as [rows]
        FROM sys.tables t
         INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
         ON p.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
         ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
         WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND p.index_id IN (1,0)    
         AND ''?'' LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchDB, '') + '%''
         AND s.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchS, '') + '%''
         AND t.name LIKE ''%' + ISNULL(@SearchTbl, '') + '%''
         AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'',''SSISDB'')
         GROUP BY s.name,t.name'
-- Remove the '--' from the last statement in the WHERE clause to exclude system tables

INSERT INTO #ServerTablesPivot (DBName, SchemaName, TableName, [RowCount])
    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQL

--SELECT * FROM #ServerTablesPivot

--Declare necessary variables
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
--Get unique values of pivot column  
SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([DBName])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [DBName] FROM #ServerTablesPivot) AS PivotExample
 
--SELECT   @PivotColumns
 
--Create the dynamic query with all the values for 
--pivot column at runtime
SET   @SQLQuery = 
    N' -- Your pivoted result comes here
    SELECT [TableName], ' + @PivotColumns + '
    FROM 
    (
        -- Source table should in a inner query
        SELECT [DbName], [TableName], [RowCount]
        FROM #ServerTablesPivot
    )AS P
    PIVOT
    (     
          -- Select the values from derived table P
          MIN([RowCount])
          FOR [DbName] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ') 
    )AS PVTTable'
 
--SELECT   @SQLQuery
--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```